# Check if entity property exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have an URL like `example.org/overview/<column>/<value>` (example: `example.org/overview/color/red`) which will cause a search in a column "color" for the value "red". This is the entity:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CarRepository")
class Car
{
    // @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    private $name;
    private $color;

    [...]
```

I think I should check if an entity property exists before I start a db query. How can I check when someone calls `example.org/overview/foo/bar` if `foo` is a valid db column (= entity property)? Does Symfony offer a simple solution here? If this might not be the case I think I have to use a hard coded white list.

Comment: There is a [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.property-exists.php) function in php.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use getClassMetadata like this:

```
$columns = $em->getClassMetadata(Car::class)->getColumnNames();

if (in_array($property, $columns)) {
   //property exists, code here
}
```

You can try also: `getFieldNames` instead of `getColumnNames`

Comment: Glad to help you @Michon

Answer (score 11):

[Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621162/4277724) is right, but the exact method `hasField()` exists:

```
$metaCar = $em->getClassMetadata(Car::class);

if ($metaCar->hasField('foo')) {
   // Property exists.
}
```

Comment: This approach is much better from a performance perspective.